# How to have a WPF application on two different machines in the same network

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a WPF application on two windows machines connected in the same network. The two systems are for redundancy purposes. 
Initially the app on machine1 keeps running. When machine1 is down for any reason, I want to start the app on machine2.
How can the app on both machines check for heartbeat of the each other? How can the app on the other machine be started when there is no heartbeat from the other?

1) The app gets info from one web service and sends it to another web service every x minutes. It is important that the info flow is not paused. Very often the machines have to be updated for maintenance or may get disconnected or accidentally shutdown. In that case, I wanted to have another machine ready to run the app meanwhile.

2) Other than these two machines, I do not have another machine to run SQL Server.

Comment: This is a bit loose.  What part are you having trouble with.  Try to break this down into smaller pieces.  You'll need to establish network communication between the two applications.  Do you need help with this part?  You'll need to establish a protocol or message format.  Do you need help with this?  You'll need to use timers or counters to manage heartbeat tracking.  Do you need help with this part?  You'll need some way to configure your application to be a master or slave.  Do you need help with this part? Etc, etc...  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Ralf, Thank you for the break down. I would need some direction on all the parts you listed.

Comment: Use MSMQ and have one of the machines set MessageQueue.DenySharedReceive on a common path between them.

Answer (score 1):

@user2347528, I can provie some direction. Although the answer is as good as your question is. Can you provide more info on:

- What is the problem you need this solution for
- Do you have a SQL Server running?
- Does your application crash or are the terminals/servers unexpectedly shutting down or option c?

Possible solution:

1.Start application on both machines. Easy one.

2.Let the application set a date value + machinename in some database table (or plain text file, or whatever means to a purpose)

3.Create a table named AppLive

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppLive](
  [MachineName] nvarchar NOT NULL,
  [Ping] [datetime] NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AppLive] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [MachineName] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

4.Check some database table (or plain text file, or whatever means to a purpose) if the application is live on some machine. If so set app in 'wait'-mode, if not set app in 'live'-mode.

Comment: Could you please provide a link on that `[ping]` and describe a bit how your solution works? Because stupid google can't search for `"[ping]"`.

Comment: 1) The app gets info from one web service and sends it to another web service every x minutes. It is important that the info flow is not paused. Very often the machines have to be updated for maintenance or may get disconnected or accidentally shutdown. In that case, I wanted to have another machine ready to run the app meanwhile. 2) Other than these two machines, I do not have another machine to run SQL Server.